# How to check cpanel clients?

Tags: dns, ip, cpanel, whm, clients

I have lots of customers in panel how to check who is using my panel services.

I have only one option:
1) Check list of all domain.
2) Check all domain one by one in network-tool.com.

Please provide me another option to check all domains information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access of your server then you can install Account DNS Check plugin on your server, With this plugins you can easily find out which domain is resolving your server OR NOT

https://www.ndchost.com/cpanel-whm/addons/accountdnscheck/